# Can't set span contents to textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get the contents of my SPAN value into a text INPUT box.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
  $('input[name=exp_total_copy]').val($('[name=document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerText]').val());
}
```

I also tried it as:
  $('input[name=exp_total_copy]').val($('document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerText').val());

Textbox:

```
<input type="text" name="exp_total_copy" id="exp_total_copy">
```

Span:

```
<span class="description" for="element_7"><b>Total: $</b><span name="grandtotal" id="grandtotal">0.00</span></span>
```

So basically when one of my textboxes onClick occurs, the MyFunction() is activated and supposed to grab the contents of the span of grandtotal and insert it into the textbox of exp_total_copy.

Comment: Is there a click event-handler somewhere that you forgot to show us?

Comment: David, on click from another textbox, onClick="myFunction()". Then within it, it grabs other data which updates the span and does perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You're not executing the query; you're giving it as a string.

```
$('input[name=exp_total_copy]').val($('[name='+document.getElementById("grandtotal").innerText+']').val());
```

But why bother with the DOM query? Just use jQuery:

```
$('input[name=exp_total_copy]').val($('[name='+$("#grandtotal").text()+']').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    You just complicated it more. what work should be

     function myFunction(){
        var spanText = $("#grandtotal").text();
        $("input[name=exp_total_copy]").val(spanText);
    }

   OR

    //using the Id attributes
    function myFunction(){
            var spanText = $('#grandtotal').text();
            $('#exp_total_copy').val(spanText);
     }
```

Comment: For some odd reason it's not updating as well. http://privates.nitetours.com is the page. When you change the Price, Male/Female count the box alll the way at the bottom isn't getting any value.